# Send an email using exchange server ONLY

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server

I need to send an email in my C# project using my companies Exchange Server.

Because someone sent out thousands of Emails from my company using a self hosted server, any attempts to not use the company Exchange Server to send the email will be squished.

I imagine I am going to need to get an Active Directory user created to do this... but what code to use?  How to do the sending?

Answer (score 2):

You can send email through Exchange using SMTP with .Net's [`SmtpClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx).
You will need a login for the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the System.Net.Mail classes to send the email via SMTP if that is enabled on your SMTP server. Alternatively you could use the [webdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) protocol to send the email via HttpRequests and HttpResponses. An example showing how to do this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms878112%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx).