# Send Email from a shared email address without SMTP server

Tags: c#, outlook, com

I want to send an email using a given shared mailbox name programmatically. I don't have access to a smtp server so I can't used System.Net.Mail.

I am using Outlook = `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`;

How can I send from a shared mailbox email rather than the default email address?

```
outlook.MailItem mail application.CreateItem(outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as outlook.MailItem;
try
   {          

    if (mail.Subject.Contains("Highway Alert")
    {

        mail.SendUsingAccount = "sharedmailboxemail@email.com"
        mail.Send();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Email Sent ");
    }
    else
```

Comment: How does Outlook send emails? Does it connect to an SMTP server or Exchange?

Comment: @gunr2171 Exchange

Comment: Have you tried any of these? https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+C%23+send+email+exchange Also, IIRC, Exchange _IS_ an SMTP server. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173530/send-an-email-using-exchange-server-only

Comment: @gunr2171 Yeah, I tried those but  I dont have access to the SMPTP server address. I can send programmatically using my default address but not from another email address.

Comment: The Exchange server most likely won't allow you to send emails as a user other than what you login with. You need to work with your IT department on this one.

Comment: Doesn't SendUsingAccount  work?

Comment: @gunr2171 you are probably right, I know in Visual Basic using Access Database it worked. I was trying to see if it is possible in C#.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko SendUsingAccount looks for account in the Account.Sesssions.Accounts but I wanted to input an email address.

Comment: If you want to send on behalf of another Exchange user, set the MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName property before sending.

Answer (score 0):

The [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property returns or sets an [Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.account) object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. For example:

```
private void SendUsingAccountExample()
{
    Outlook.MailItem mail = Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.Subject = "Our itinerary";
    mail.Attachments.Add(@"c:\travel\itinerary.doc", Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    Outlook.Account account = Application.Session.Accounts["Hotmail"];
    mail.SendUsingAccount = account;
    mail.Send();
}
```

See [Send a mail item by using a Hotmail account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-send-a-mail-item-by-using-a-hotmail-account?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Please remember that another account should be configured in Outlook in that case.

The [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862145.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property makes sense only in case of Exchange profiles/accounts. Moreover, you need to have the required permissions to send on behalf of another person. See [Issue with SentOnBehalfOfName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180066/issue-with-sentonbehalfofname) for a similar discussion.

In case if you have multiple accounts configured in the profile you can use the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311.aspx) property which allows to an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent.

```
 Sub SendUsingAccount() 
  Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
  For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
    oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
    oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
    oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
    oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
    oMail.Send 
   End If 
  Next 
 End Sub
```